# How to execute a Postgresql procedure through Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-8.4

How can I execute a procedure like `SELECT my_proc()` inside my POSTGRESQL database using Windows Task Scheduler? Is it possible to make a script to call my procedure every 5 minutes? If it's possible I need one.

I can't use pgAgent in my environment, sorry guys!

Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Task Scheduler to run `psql` on the desired schedule, with a command like:

```
psql -U username -d databasename -w -c 'SELECT my_procedure()'
```

and put the password in your `.pgpass` file, or set a `PGPASS` environment variable in the task.

You don't need any kind of script unless you want to do command specific error handling.

Comment: Use double quotes around the select statement

Comment: @Derek Why? It's not doing string interpolation, so single quotes are fine.

Comment: Running on Windows Server 2012 R2, using single quotes gives ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'SELECT", using double quotes works.

Comment: @Derek Ok, that's a Windows cmd.exe quirk, then, not PostgreSQL. Good tip for Windows users though.